# Excel, exactly what does this formula say, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN( )+28,3))?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I found this formula on the web a long time ago. =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN( )+28,3))
It works perfectly for what I am using it for, however, now I am trying to adapt the formula to another job but I don't understand it as well as I thought I did so I can't make the proper reference changes.

The working formula resides in cell V6. It is getting the value from cell C38. The exact same formula is in the next cell of the same row, W6, and gets it's value from C39. And so on, 12 times, for each month.

On the new sheet I am working on the application is the same but the columns and rows are different. The formula would reside in AY3 and should give me the value in cell AF3.

Each application is displaying a value horizontally, for each month, across a row, based on values for corresponding months from the same column.

I am hoping that if I understand the formula better I can adapt it to my new page. I have done a lot of searching, and though I can find lots of information on both "indirect" and "address", I cannot find information on the combination used in this formula.

Comment: The formula transposes data from a  column to a row. If you are on Excel 365 you can use `MTRANS` instead: `=MTRANS(AF3:AF15)`

Comment: It's using the numeric representation of the column. So A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, etc.. it adds 28 to it, so 28 columns to the right of A, B or C. The same can be accomplished with index: if you want to start at C38, use: `=INDEX(C:C,COLUMN(A:A)+37))` if you drag it to the right it increases the column # which references the row index.  Benefit of INDEX versus INDIRECT (or OFFSET) is that it's not volatile, meaning it won't result in a recalculation of your Excel at any change in the sheet, each time, making sheets possibly slow.

Comment: @Ike MTRANS being TRANSPOSE I don't think that's ment here. But in that case TOCOL could do it as well.

Comment: Seconding @P.b, this formula should be rewritten to avoid using `INDIRECT`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, especially P.b who explained to me what's happening.